# How to get more feeds from RSS url?

Tags: rss, feed, fiddler, feedly

Let's take for example the following rss-link:
http://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/feed/

As you can see, the RSS publishs only 1 item at a time.

However, RSS Readers services like Feedly (and more), success to retrive more items:
http://feedly.com/index.html#subscription%2Ffeed%2Fhttp%3A%2F%2Fyourdailygerman.wordpress.com%2Ffeed%2F

I opened fiddler and I saw they have their own API (following "count" paramter as the items count to get), and I wonder - How they do that???

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what question you're asking. It *sounds* like you're asking: *How can a webpage look at a query string parameter and behave differently?* which doesn't seem like a valid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get more item from a feed if it's the first time you fetch it... however (and this is what Feedly does!), you can store the content of today, so that when new items are added tomorrow, you have the items from today and tomorrow... etc. Eventually you'll have enough data!

Comment: Ok, as I thought.. Well, it's a little bit crazy to create that kind of mechanism by myself.. ;)

Thank you!

Comment: You don't have to create it by yourself of course, some services like [Superfeedr](https://superfeedr.com) do that on your behalf :)