# RSS Feed - increase number of news articles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rss

With Rails and the `feedjira` gem, I am using an RSS feed to get news articles from a website like so:

```
Article.update_from_feed("http://feeds.feedburner.com/CoinDesk")



def self.update_from_feed(feed_url)
    feed = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse(feed_url)
    add_entries(feed.entries)
  end
```

However, by default I get a relatively small number of news.

Is there an option I can pass such that I can increase the number of news I get from that website?

Comment: Are you sure that is Feedjira and not feedburner that is limiting the number of articles?

Comment: No. I don't know which one sets the limit. In case it is feedburner, is there a way of increasing the limit?

Comment: I don't know - I haven't used FB in years. But I remember it being kind of crap whenever you want to do something remotely advanced.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get more feeds from RSS url?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110170/how-to-get-more-feeds-from-rss-url)

Answer (score 0):

This is a [duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110170/how-to-get-more-feeds-from-rss-url/24121026#24121026). Feedjira will *only* be able to provide you with the content that's in the feed t the moment you poll it.
Use feed APIs like [Superfeedr](http://superfeedr.com) which store the content of feeds if you need more.